# Payment success but is amount is due in backend order [Magento PayPal]

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, paypal-express

My Magento is redirecting to PayPal payment site and after payment is success, it sends back some details but in "order" it still showing
[image]

the payment is due.
What can I do to change it to paid?

Comment: I think I found the culprit but ..... not sure 100%

Comment: Apparently wrong settings, is that possible to change some values to default just updating software ?